# I/flutter (31065): No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to implement [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) library for almost two days now. I have done all necessary configurations from both localhost and the firebase console.

Dependencies:

```yaml
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  mvc_pattern: ^5.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^0.5.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.4
```

Below is the `_googleSignUp()` custom function.

```dart
Future<void> _googleSignUp() async {
      try {
        final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
          scopes: [
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
          ],
          hostedDomain: '',
          clientId: '',
        );

        final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
            await googleUser.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: googleAuth.accessToken, accessToken: googleAuth.idToken);
        final FirebaseUser user =
            (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        print('Current user: ${user.displayName}');

        return user;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
```

The problem is, whenever I trigger the `_googleSignUp()` funtion with a `button` click, I keep getting this log below and then nothing happens.

```
I/flutter (31065): No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in
```

Developers how do we fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with this problem for an entire day, I realized the google_sign_in throws that exception if you also have the flutter_facebook_login plugin but haven't configured it as per [these instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login).

Nonsensical error message had me going in circles.

Comment: I hage same issue.
you solve my  problem.

Comment: This should be considered the answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the flutter_auth plugin to the latest version:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-installing-tab-

Comment: are you using the stable channel?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360060/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-init-on-channel-plugin

Comment: Yes I have seen that question and tried the solutions multiple times already but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is changing the AppDelegate.swift file in the ios/Runner folder to:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```