# How to resolve package conflict issue in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, flutter-packages

I tried to use google signin and facebbok auth or facebook sigin in my flutter app . I got a perfect output when i add anyone of the faceebook auth or google sigin package . When i try  to add both I got a package conflict error

**I also tried for both like this**  :   *import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' as  **google**;*

But that does not work

**flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0

google_sign_in: ^4.1.1**

And the error which i got is :I/flutter (13976): **MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)**

**This is my flutter doctor:**

C:\Users\Administrator>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 2.0.5 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
• Framework revision adc687823a (6 weeks ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
• Engine revision b09f014e96
• Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• HD1901 (mobile) • 5c628c62 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
• Chrome (web)    • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
• Edge (web)      • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.66

• No issues found!

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360060/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-init-on-channel-plugin ?

Comment: Thank you for the valueable response , Yes i have tried that too.